# .NET Core 2.1: AddHsts() and AddHttpsRedirection() not defined

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, https, compiler-errors, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a .NET Core 2.1 application and want to use HTTPs according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.1) article. So I added

```
services.AddHsts(options =>
{
    options.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(60);
});
services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
{
    options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status307TemporaryRedirect;
    options.HttpsPort = 5001;
});
```

to the `ConfigureServices(...)` method and

```
app.UseHsts();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

to the `Configure(...)` method. I checked the namespace of the methods and they should be present in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder ([e.g. UseHsts()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.hstsbuilderextensions.usehsts?view=aspnetcore-2.1)), but all of them generate the compiler error

> 'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseHsts' and no accessible extension method 'UseHsts' accepting a first argument of type 'IApplicationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

or

> 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddHttpsRedirection' and no accessible extension method 'AddHttpsRedirection' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**Am I missing a `using` directive or a specific NuGet package? How can I use those methods?**

Comment: Did you include the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` meta package? I just created a fresh ASP.NET Core 2.1 project, and can't reproduce the error.

Comment: @janw You were right. `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` was missing. Write an answer so i can accept it

Comment: Btw.: What IDE are you using? Typically the IDE will mark the error and suggest to add the missing using statement for you.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen I am using VisualStudio 2017. For whatever reason it doesn't make any suggestions

Comment: You know ReSharper (jetbrains) VS plugin? May be worth evaluating...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most dependencies of ASP.NET Core are contained in the [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App) meta package, which also includes the extensions methods from the question. After adding this package, the methods should become available.

The `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` package is automatically included by the IDE when creating a new project, but may be missing when [upgrading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage?view=aspnetcore-2.1#migrate) or converting an existing project.